# Flipping text that is already rotated

Tags: html, css

I could use some help flipping text horizontally after rotating it 90 degrees. [Here is a code pen showing what I'm doing](https://codepen.io/yoursweater/pen/QgREKZ). Basically, I'm trying to flip a couple of the seaweed pieces around so that they face different directions and look a little more natural. I've tried using transform: scaleX(-1) but that hasn't worked. I think it's because I"m already rotating the characters ("~") 90 degrees, but I'm not positive.

```
.seaweed {
  font-size:20em;
  color:green;
  transform:rotate(90deg);
  width:100px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-100px;
  margin:0;
  animation: float 3s infinite;
}

#seaweed1 {
  left:5%;
}

#seaweed2 {
  left:12%;
  animation-delay:1s;
}

#seaweed3 {
  left:50%;
}

#seaweed4 {
  left:54%;
  animation-delay:0.5s;
}

#seaweed5 {
  left:65%;
}

#seaweed6 {
  left:75%;
  animation-delay:0.7s;
}

@keyframes float {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(40px) translateX(0) rotate(90deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) translateX(0) rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, love your animation! Second, sadly, the inability to flip is a direct result of the animation. It would seem as though you can't use `scale` in conjunction with `animation`. You might be able to work around this by doing the flip in each of the keyframes, but doing so renders the animation very 'choppy' for me.

Comment: There might be a more efficient way of doing this, but you can use `:nth-child()` to add a `rotateX()` with a second animation https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YQbGGj